# Keypress event handler for a11y compliance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I am trying to make my working React.JS app compliant with accessibility standards.

As a part of the exercise, I added `onKeyDown` handlers to where I am using `onClick` handlers. I also wrap those handlers with a special wrapper function that checks which key is pressed. The actual code is below:

```
import { KeyboardEvent } from 'react';
enum Keys {
  TAB = 9,
}
const handleKeyPress = (cb: () => void) => (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
  if (e.keyCode !== Keys.TAB) cb();
};
export { handleKeyPress };
```

I use it as:

```
<div
  className={classes.link_complete}
  onClick={handleOnClick}
  onKeyDown={handleKeyPress(() => {
    handleOnClick();
  })}
  tabIndex={0}
  role="button"
>
```

This is working fine. However, there are situations when I want to pass the actual event as an argument to the function wrapped by the `handleKeyPress` function. That is not working for me. I tried:

```
onClick={handleViewInfoClick}
onKeyDown={(e) => {
  console.log('detected keydown');
  handleKeyPress(() => {
    console.log('inside handler');
    handleViewInfoClick(e);
  });
}}
```

That is not working. Keydown events are detected, hence I see `detected keydown` printed. Yet, the code inside does not get invoked.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `handleKeyPress` returns a function (which makes sense, since you usually use the return value for `onKeyDown`), but you're not calling it in your example where you're trying to use the event object, you're just calling `handleKeyPress` to create the function and then not calling the function.

I would modify `handleKeyPress` so it passes along the event object:

```typescript
const handleKeyPress = (cb: (e: KeyboardEvent) => void) => (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
  //                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  if (e.keyCode !== Keys.TAB) cb(e);
  //                             ^
};
```

Then the usage would be almost exactly like your original usage, you'd just include the handler:

```
<div
  className={classes.link_complete}
  onClick={handleOnClick}
  onKeyDown={handleKeyPress((e) => handleViewInfo(e))}
  tabIndex={0}
  role="button"
>
```

or more succinctly:

```
<div
  className={classes.link_complete}
  onClick={handleOnClick}
  onKeyDown={handleKeyPress(handleViewInfo)}
  tabIndex={0}
  role="button"
>
```